# Query optimization for tournament scoring tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, query-optimization

I have two tables in a tournament-related database and I need to know the most optimized SQL query to generate the correct overall results.  The results must show the total points scored, minus any penalties, and scores that are tied should be broken based on the person who reached that score first.

In the database tables, I have an event log where each score is added as teams proceed through the tournament, and I have another table which shows which team is part of which tournament.

```
Table "xTournamentTeam" (connects a team to a tournament)
=======================
+-----+------------+--------+--------------+
| nID | Team Name  | TeamID | TournamentID |
+-----+------------+--------+--------------+
|  1  | Team A     | 12     | 25           |
|  2  | Team B     | 13     | 25           |
|  3  | Team C     | 14     | 25           |
|  4  | Team D     | 15     | 25           |
|  3  | Team A     | 12     | 32           |
|  4  | Team B     | 13     | 32           |
+-----+------------+--------+--------------+

Table "nEventLog" (records scoring during a tournament)
=================
+-----+---------------+---------+----------+----------------+-----------------------+
| nID | nTournamentID | nTeamID | nPoints  | nPointsPenalty | nEventTime            |
+-----+---------------+---------+----------+----------------|-----------------------+
|  1  | 25            | 15      | 100      | 0              | 1/24/2013 6:05:14 AM  |
|  2  | 25            | 14      | 100      | 0              | 1/24/2013 6:29:55 AM  |
|  3  | 25            | 14      | 100      | 25             | 1/24/2013 7:09:34 AM  |
|  4  | 25            | 12      | 100      | 0              | 1/24/2013 7:12:28 AM  |
|  5  | 25            | 12      | 100      | 0              | 1/24/2013 8:42:59 AM  |
|  6  | 25            | 12      | 100      | 50             | 1/24/2013 8:43:36 AM  |
|  7  | 25            | 14      | 100      | 0              | 1/24/2013 9:15:24 AM  |
|  8  | 25            | 15      | 100      | 0              | 1/24/2013 9:15:27 AM  |
|  9  | 32            | 12      | 100      | 0              | 1/28/2013 8:33:49 AM  |
|  10 | 32            | 13      | 100      | 25             | 1/28/2013 2:15:12 PM  |
|  11 | 32            | 12      | 100      | 10             | 1/28/2013 7:12:25 AM  |
|  12 | 32            | 13      | 100      | 0              | 1/29/2013 7:18:06 AM  |
+-----+---------------+---------+----------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

In the case of the above data, the query I need should generate the following results for Tournament #25:

```
+-------+------------+--------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| nRank | Team Name  | TeamID | TournamentID | nTotalPoints  | nTotalPointsPenalty | nLatestEventTime            |
+-------+------------+--------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+
|  1    | Team A     | 12     | 25           | 300           | 50                  | 1/24/2013 8:43:36 AM        |
|  2    | Team C     | 14     | 25           | 300           | 25                  | 1/24/2013 9:15:24 AM        |
|  3    | Team D     | 15     | 25           | 200           | 0                   | 1/24/2013 9:15:27 AM        |
|  4    | Team B     | 13     | 25           | 0             | 0                   |                             |
+-------+------------+--------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

For load purposes, I'm trying to avoid sub-queries at all costs since the final query should be as optimized as possible.  The "nRank" column can be generated programatically... MySQL shouldn't have to return it, but I'm shoing it for reference.

The query I have that is the closest is this one, but it doesn't return "Team B" because they don't have any records in the "nEventLog" table for nTournamentID #25:

```
SELECT xTournamentTeam.nTeamName
     , sum(nEventLog.nPoints) AS nTotalPoints
     , xTournamentTeam.nTeamID
     , max(nEventLog.nEventTime) AS nLatestEventTime
     , sum(nEventLog.nPointsPenalty) AS nTotalPenaltyPoints
     , xTournamentTeam.nTournamentID
FROM
  xTournamentTeam
LEFT OUTER JOIN nEventLog
ON xTournamentTeam.nTeamID = nEventLog.nTeamID
WHERE
  xTournamentTeam.nTournamentID = 33
  AND nEventLog.nTournamentID = 33
GROUP BY
  xTournamentTeam.nID
, xTournamentTeam.nTournamentID
ORDER BY
  nTotalPoints DESC
, nLatestEventTime DESC
```

I'm certainly no expert in MySQL queries, and I've been working on this for two days without much success, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you run an `explain` on your `select` statement ?

Comment: What do you mean by "For load purposes, I'm trying to avoid sub-queries at all costs since the final query should be as optimized as possible."?  Can you document why subqueryies would not be optimized?  This goes against what I know about MySQL in particular and SQL optimizers in general.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess I've seen several posts against using sub-queries to go in that direction. From what I've heard, they place too much stress on the server for something that could be done with sub-queries. I don't have anything against them, but I do very much need to have the most optimized query.  Currently, I'm doing the above with multiple queries and PHP, and the load on the server during tournament time (with thousands visting the stats pages and refreshing constantly) is pretty bad, so optimization is key.

Comment: @Michael . . . the execution engines of almost all SQL engines don't know anything about subqueries.  They are executing data flow operations.  Subqueries are syntax conventions.  They may or may not optimize well for a given engine, but that is true of most SQL constructs.

Comment: @Daedalus Since I'm not much of an expert, the results from an EXPLAIN don't tell me much, but here they are:

Comment: @Daedalus
**id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra**
1 SIMPLE xTournamentTeam ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 65 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

1
SIMPLE
nEventLog
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
312
Using where

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. Do you think there's any possibility then for sub-queries in the statement above to fix the issue and still keep it optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your logic a little bit, I think it's working:

```
SELECT
          xTournamentTeam.TeamName
         , sum(nEventLog.nPoints) AS nTotalPoints
         , xTournamentTeam.TeamID
         , max(nEventLog.nEventTime) AS nLatestEventTime
         , sum(nEventLog.nPointsPenalty) AS nTotalPenaltyPoints
         , xTournamentTeam.TournamentID
FROM
      xTournamentTeam 
LEFT OUTER JOIN nEventLog
    ON xTournamentTeam.TournamentID = nEventLog.nTournamentID AND xTournamentTeam.TeamID = nEventLog.nTeamID
WHERE
      xTournamentTeam.TournamentID = 25          
GROUP BY
      xTournamentTeam.TeamID
    , xTournamentTeam.TournamentID 
    , xTournamentTeam.TeamName
ORDER BY 
    nTotalPoints DESC
```

If you need, you can format nulls to represent 0 or something else.

Comment: I'm running a few tests on it now, but so far it looks like it's working. :)

Comment: Made only one change: "ORDER BY nTotalPoints DESC, nLatestEventTime".  In case of a tie-breaker, this ensures that the team who received the score first gets the lead.  Otherwise your SQL query works perfectly! Thanks for your help... the "LEFT OUTER JOIN" statement you added is ingenious!